# Where to place common function which will be used by class and class member?

Tags: c++, methods, composition

For example,

```
class B {
  int* b1;
  int* b2;
  B(int* x, int* y) {
     b1 = x;
     b2 = y;
  }

};

class A {
  int* a1;
  int* a2;
  B* b1;
  public:
  A() {
    a1 = new int;
    a2 = new int;
    b1 = new B1(a1, b1);
  }
};
```

I want to access values pointed by a1 and a2 from objects of both class A & B. Where i should write function for the same, so  that this function can be called by objects of A and objects of B. ?

Comment: I think you are looking for inheritance, not aggregation.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen no I need to pass few values to class members , this class member is again needs few values from main class and has some different purpose.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking.

Comment: "Feature envy" smells strong here. I'd suggest reconsidering design of these classes. Why do they share resources?

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Create a public getter for a1 (and a2), for example `get_a1`, then pass pointer to A to B on A init. Then from B you would be able to `b.a_ptr->get_a1();` But it is really unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this special context, you are only passing pointers so the objects pointed by `a1` and `a2` **are** the objects pointed by `b1` and `b2`. On the other hand, an `A` object knows what `B` it contains, but an instance of `B` has no knowledge about being contained in an `A`.

Because of that, I think that the function manipulating the pointed objects should be declared in `B` class. Then if the existence of B is member of the public API of A (with a getter for example) it is enough:

```
class B {
    ...
    void do_something(...) {
        // do something with objects pointed by b1 and b2
    }
};
...
A a;
a.getB()->do_something();
...
```

If the `B` member of `A` is an *implementation detail*, you should declare a relay method in A:

```
class A {
    ...
    void do_something(...) {     // delegate to the `B` member
        b1->do_something(...);
    }
};
...
A a;
a.do_something(...);
...
```

Comment: Why reject the edit?  `B` does not contain `A`.  It is _contained in_ `A`.  If you don't like my edit you should fix this yourself.

Comment: @PaulSanders: When I opened your edit, another one had already voted *not an improvement...*. English is not my first language, but what I mean here is not only that a B does not knows whether it is contained in a A but also that it cannot know in what `A` it is contained. I felt that your edit was not clear about that. I'm really sorry about it, because I generally gladly accept any edit that improve my (poor) English.

Comment: OK Serge, I will edit it again.  I know what you meant to say (and you're absolutely right) and wanted to make it clear, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

you could friend the classes vice versa.
[look here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend).

This allows "cross usage" of members and methods

If you only want one function to access both A's and B's private members and methods, you can friend this specific function.

Comment: This also couples the classes to the extreme. I wouldn't recommend that.